# postfix with zeyple - Relay access denied

Tags: email, postfix-mta

I want to use zeyple to encrypt outgoing mails send by my server.

"Zeyple is a Postfix filter/hook to automatically encrypt outgoing emails with GPG/PGP."

https://github.com/infertux/zeyple

I installed and set up postfix to send mails only:

$ sudo apt-get install postfix

```
General type of mail configuration: Internet Site

System mail name: <hostname>
```

In /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
#inet_interfaces = all
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
```

Sending unencrypted mails works fine at this point.

After installing zeyple with the tutorial from
https://github.com/infertux/zeyple/blob/master/INSTALL.md
and setting

```
content_filter = zeyple
```

in main.cf i get a "Relay access denied"

$ date | mail -s testmail user@somemail.com

```
<user@somemail.com>: Command died with status 1: "/usr/local/bin/zeyple.py".
    Command output: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
    "/usr/local/bin/zeyple.py", line 274, in <module>
    zeyple.process_message(message, recipients)   File
    "/usr/local/bin/zeyple.py", line 126, in process_message
    self._send_message(out_message, recipient)   File
    "/usr/local/bin/zeyple.py", line 260, in _send_message
    smtp.sendmail(message['From'], recipient, message.as_string())   File
    "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 747, in sendmail     raise
    SMTPRecipientsRefused(senderrs) smtplib.SMTPRecipientsRefused:
    {'user@somemail.com': (454, '4.7.1 <user@somemail.com>: Relay access
    denied')}
```

$ cat /var/log/zeyple.log

```
2017-07-01 11:43:17,019 29616 INFO Zeyple ready to encrypt outgoing emails
2017-07-01 11:43:17,020 29616 INFO Processing outgoing message <20170701094316.EED64817E4@<hostname>.dedicated.hosteurope.de>
2017-07-01 11:43:17,020 29616 INFO Recipient: user@somemail.com
2017-07-01 11:43:17,020 29616 INFO Trying to encrypt for user@somemail.com
2017-07-01 11:43:17,034 29616 INFO Key ID: <some-key>
2017-07-01 11:43:17,054 29616 INFO Sending message <20170701094316.EED64817E4@<hostname>.dedicated.hosteurope.de>
```

$ postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
content_filter = zeyple
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = <hostname>.dedicated.hosteurope.de, localhost.dedicated.hosteurope.de, , localhost
myhostname = <hostname>.dedicated.hosteurope.de
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking /var/log/mail.log i found the following message

```
Jul  2 11:22:07 hostname postfix/smtpd[8984]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[::1]: 454 4.7.1 <user@somemail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<user@hostname.dedicated.hosteurope.de> to=<user@somemail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<hostname.dedicated.hosteurope.de>
Jul  2 11:22:07 hostname postfix/smtpd[8984]: lost connection after RSET from localhost[::1]
```

the solution was to edit a part which was added from the zeyple install instruction in the following file:

/etc/postfix/master.cf

( replace 127.0.0.0/8 with [::1]/128 )

```
#  -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
  -o mynetworks=[::1]/128
#  -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=127.0.0.0/8
  -o smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts=[::1]/128
```